# Can two different multiplicative systems give same localisation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization

Can we have two different multiplicative systems $S_1$ and $S_2$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ having same localisations $\mathbb{Z}_{S_1}=\mathbb{Z}_{S_2}$? 
I have a trivial solution by taking two different subrings and adjoining $1$ to them gives required $S_1,S_2$ but that collapses the localizations to trivial rings. I wanted something more interesting. Considering multiplicative systems without $0$...

Comment: $\{4^n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ and $\{2^n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ should yield the same localization, right? More generally, the localization at an element $p_1^{n_1} \cdot \ldots \cdot p_r^{n_r}$ is the same as the localization of $p_1 \cdot \ldots \cdot p_r$.

Comment: yup...$m/{4^n}=m(1/{2^n}\cdot 1/{2^n})$ and $k/{2^n}={k2^n}/{4^n}$...got it

Answer (score 4):

Here is a very general criterion.  Let $A$ be a commutative ring and let $S\subseteq A$ be a multiplicatively closed subset.  Define the *saturated closure* of $S$ to be $$\operatorname{sat}(S)=\{a\in A: a\text{ divides some element of }S\}.$$ Note that $\operatorname{sat}(\operatorname{sat}(S))=\operatorname{sat}(S)$ so this really is a "closure" operation.

> **Theorem**: Let $S,T\subseteq A$ be multiplicatively closed subsets of $A$.  Then the localizations $A_S$ and $A_T$ are isomorphic as $A$-algebras iff $\operatorname{sat}(S)=\operatorname{sat}(T)$.

This gives lots of examples.  For instance, in the case $A=\mathbb{Z}$, you can take any nonzero integer $n$ and let $S\subset\mathbb{Z}$ be the multiplicatively closed subset subset generated by $n$.  Then $\operatorname{sat}(S)$ will be the multiplicatively closed subset generated by the prime factors of $n$.  So if $m$ is any other integer with the same set of prime factors as $n$ and $T$ is the multiplicatively closed subset generated by $m$, then $\mathbb{Z}_S\cong\mathbb{Z}_T$.

*Proof of Theorem*: Note that in any commutative ring, any divisor of a unit is a unit.  It follows that for any $A$-algebra $B$, every element of $S$ is a unit in $B$ iff every element of $\operatorname{sat}(S)$ is a unit in $B$.  Thus the localizations $A_S$ and $A_{\operatorname{sat}(S)}$ have the same universal property as $A$-algebras, and so they are isomorphic.  It follows immediately that if $\operatorname{sat}(S)=\operatorname{sat}(T)$ then $A_S\cong A_T$.

Conversely, I claim that $\operatorname{sat}(S)$ is exactly the set of elements of $A$ which are units in $A_S$.  By the discussion above, every element of $\operatorname{sat}(S)$ is a unit in $A_S$.  Conversely, suppose $a\in A$ is a unit in $A_S$.  This means there exists $b\in B$ and $s\in S$ such that $\frac{a}{1}\cdot\frac{b}{s}=\frac{1}{1}$ in $A_S$, which means there exists $t\in S$ such that $t(ab-s)=0$.  But then $abt=st$ and so $a$ divides the element $st\in S$, so $a\in\operatorname{sat}(S)$.

It follows that if $A_S\cong A_T$ then $\operatorname{sat}(S)=\operatorname{sat}(T)$, since the elements of $A$ that are units in $A_S$ and $A_T$ are the same.

Comment: I agree with the last sentence if $A_S, A_T$ have the usual $A$-algebra structure with $A$-multiplication defined by the inclusion map. Does this still hold if $A_S\cong A_T$ as $A$-algebras only when both are equipped with some other $A$-multiplication? Or does this never occur?

Comment: @inf: If they are equipped with arbitrary $A$-algebra structures then all bets are off.  Then you might as well just be asking for $A_S$ and $A_T$ to be isomorphic as *rings* (since you can transport the $A$-algebra structure of one along any ring isomorphism).  For instance, if $A=k[t]$ then the localizations $A[(t+c)^{-1}]$ isomorphic as rings for each $c\in k$ since there is an automorphism of $A$ sending $t$ to $t+c$.